# Is the fact that Coruscant is a city-planet impressive?

Tags: star-wars, planets

In *The Phantom Menace*, while arriving at Coruscant, a crew member tells Anakin the following:

> Coruscant, the capital of the Republic. The entire planet is
>   one big city.

The way it's phrased seems to imply that Coruscant is one of a kind, that any other cities in the galaxy don't cover their entire planet.

Is this correct? Is there evidence that Coruscant is special in this regard?

Comment: Please help me adding the right tags.

Comment: Which Canon are you interested in? In legends Canon, there are multiple examples of an [ecumenopolis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecumenopolis) (city-wide planet). I'm not so sure about MickeyCanon

Comment: @SSumner, any canon is OK.

Comment: did my answer answer your question? If not, what other information are you looking for?

Comment: @SSumner, sorry, yes it did. I forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are referring to is known as an [ecumenopolis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ecumenopolis), which is a planet-spanning city. in Legends canon, there are a multitude of other examples of this, which include [Nar Shaddaa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nar_Shaddaa/Legends) and [Taris](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taris/Legends), among numerous others.

Of these, Nar Shaddaa, the moon of the Hutts' heavily polluted homeworld Nal Hutta, is probably the best known in the expanded universe, appearing in several dozen works.

> Nar Shaddaa was the largest moon of Nal Hutta. More commonly known as the Vertical City, the Smugglers' Moon and Little Coruscant, Nar Shaddaa was similar to Coruscant in that its surface was entirely overgrown with city sprawl for millennia. But unlike Coruscant—which was only relatively rundown and dangerous on the lower and under levels of the world city—Nar Shaddaa was filthy, polluted, and infested with crime everywhere.

Per JasonBaker's comment, both Taris and Nar Shaddaa appear in the Disney universe, but not enough to confirm if either are an ecumenopolis. I'm not aware of any other examples in the revised Disney canon, but I wouldn't be surprised to see one pop up at some point.

Comment: @DvK it's not like you would have gotten any rep out of it :) Mr. 427 daily rep

Comment: 182 and unlikely to go much higher today (capped out - bounty cost). You're right, though I could have gotten 15 more for accept :) What REALLY ticks me off is that I actually researched ecumenopolises 2 days ago, answering another question. I feel like Hermione in Snape's Potions class

Comment: Taris and Nar Shaddaa have both appeared in Disney Canon (Taris was in *Aftermath* and Nar Shaddaa was in a couple of the Marvel comics), but I'm not sure if they're still ecumenopolii

Comment: It is hard enough to believe that a city could encompass an entire planet;  it is impossible for me to accept KOTOR's claim that the Taris planet-city was built in only 100 years.

Comment: @wadcheber maybe constructing in 100 years, but is it really too hard to believe a world that's been populated for many millenia at a high technological rate would encompass an entire planet? (we don't know how big around coruscant is either, so it could be a big or small)